# Order from query

Tags: mysql

I'm doing the following query in MySQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM objets
WHERE ID in (2608523,4898248,1733606,91654)
```

The question is that in the resulting query, records come with a list ordered by ID ascending.

What I really need is just the supplied registers come with the same order as indicated in the WHERE clause.

Is there anyway I accomplish this?

Comment: Another option `ORDER BY FIELD(ID,2608523,4898248,1733606,91654)`

Comment: @Mihai that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by a calculation lke this

```
SELECT * 
FROM objets
WHERE ID in (2608523,4898248,1733606,91654)
ORDER BY POSITION(',' || ID || ',' 
               IN ',' || '2608523,4898248,1733606,91654' || ',')
```

The commas are concatenated in case there are partitial matching numbers like `2608523,26085,608523,260852`

Edit:

The previous is a generic solution based on Standard SQL, but @Mihai showed a shorter version using a MySQL extension as a comment to the OP:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(ID,2608523,4898248,1733606,91654)
```